# Provisonal Patent Cover Sheet More Questions

Tags: provisional-application, provisional

1. Should I sign my name in the sheet or type it like /Firstname Lastname/
2. Is the date field filled by me? If that is the case, should I put the date where I am when posting the pdf and everything?
3. There are two Telephone fields on the sheet? Why is that?
4. On the micro entity sheet, am I the person i.e. the inventor the who would fill the fields under:
   SIGNATURE by an authorized party set forth in 37 CFR 1.33(b)

Lastly, should the pages on my PDF file be numbered or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. 37 CFR 1.4(d) identifies the acceptable uses of the "slanted" S-signature, including the electronic filing of a patent application.[USPTO 37 CFR 1.4](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9020-appx-r.html#d0e313174)
2. the only "date" on a PPA cover sheet (PTO/SB/16) would pertain to the date of the signature.
3. there are spaces for two phone numbers because they are possibly two different offices; one is for correspondence (e.g., inventor, employer, patent attorney) and the other is for the signatory (i.e., the inventor or patent attorney).
4. the "authorized party" is either the sole inventor, all of the joint inventors, or the registered patent attorney representing them.
   [USPTO help page - micro-entity signatures](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/law/sign_micro.jsp)

Pages of a provisional application for patent filed electronically as a PDF need not have visible page numbers, but having them can make future reference more efficient. There are special rules about documents such as computer listings of large biological sequence listings and large tables. There are PCT rules about page numbering for drawings.